# Splitting a string of text into completely separate arrays by spaces?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know how to split a string in general using the .split() method. i.e

```
function split(txt) {
    return txt.split(' ');
}
```

would return `['hello', 'world']` if the `'txt'` was `"hello world"`.

What I want to do is split the exact same way (by the spaces), but instead of pushing them into the same array, I want to push to completely separate arrays without knowing the length of the string or how many spaces there are in the string.

For example, I want to return `[['hello'], ['world']]`

Comment: `"Hello World".split(" ").map(x => Array(x))`?

Comment: @CRice An answer shouldn't be in the comments section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the result in an array.

```js
function split(txt) {
    return txt.split(' ').map(s => [s]);
}

console.log(split('hello world'));
```

Comment: This is perfect and works just as I need it to! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function split(txt) {
  return txt.split(' ').map(function(str) {
    return [str];
  });
}

console.log(split('hello world'));
```